# "Do you want" vs "would you like?"

Tags: questions

As a non-native speaker when I talk to native speakers, I tend to use *"Do you want ...."* instead of *"Would you like....?"* e.g. "*Do you want we have the meeting in this room?" "Do you want we have lunch in that restaurant?"*

My question is do native speakers feel different when I ask them with to want verb? Does it sound unnatural to them? What about *"Do you like?"* instead of "*Would you like?"*

Comment: "Do you want we have lunch in that restaurant?" is not grammatically correct.  It should be something like "Do you want **to have lunch** in that restaurant?"

Comment: Sorry, I meant to link *[What is the difference between “do you like” and “would you like”?](/questions/29804)* Also related is *[Would you like to/ care to](/questions/110273)*

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The difference, when there is one, is about being polite:

**Would you like some milk in your tea?** [a polite way to ask the question]

If you know the person and the person is your friend, you can say:

**Do you want milk in your tea**?

It really is as simple as that.

Please note the grammar point below: 
Do you **want we** have the meeting in this room?" "Do you **want we** have lunch in that restaurant?"= To be grammatical, **those need to be changed to**:

> "Do you want us to have the meeting in this room?"
>
> "Do you want us to have lunch in that restaurant?"

Please note: to want [someone] to do something is one expression.
Another is: Do you want x? Do you want lunch now?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps in some context there's a difference, but in general, I think English speakers would see these as synonymous phrases.